# Merging DataFrames with Partial String Matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge two dataframes of different sizes based on partial match of the column 'name' and 'sub_name' (and full match of values in column A):

```
  sub_name  val_1    A
0      AAA      2  208
1      AAB      4  208
2      AAC      8  208
3      BAA      7  210
4      CAA      4  213
5      CAC      6  213
6      CAD      2  213
7      CAE      3  213
8      EAA      8  222
9      FAA      3  223

    name  val_2    A
0   XAAA      1  208
1  AABYY      5  208
2   BAAZ      9  210
3   CAAY      5  213
4  YCABX      8  213
5  XXCAC      6  213
6  YCADZ      3  213
7   XDAA      6  215
8   EAAX      4  222
```

the codes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sub_name': ['AAA','AAB','AAC','BAA','CAA','CAC','CAD','CAE','EAA', 'FAA'], 
'val_1': [2,4,8,7,4,6,2,3,8,3], 
'A':[208,208,208,210,213,213,213,213,222,223]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['XAAA','AABYY','BAAZ','CAAY','YCABX','XXCAC','YCADZ','XDAA','EAAX'], 
'val_2': [1,5,9,5,8,6,3,6,4], 
'A': [208,208,210,213,213,213,213,215,222]})
```

**Edit:** I want to do an outer merge of these two dataframes – if there is no match, keep the rows, if there is a partial match (between sub_name and name) and **also if the values in column A match, merge them together**. If there is a partial match between name and sub_name but the column A values don't match, keep both rows.

I am trying to obtain:

```
     name  val_1  val_2    A
0     AAA    2.0    1.0  208
1     AAB    4.0    5.0  208
2     AAC    8.0    NaN  208
3     BAA    7.0    9.0  210
4     CAA    4.0    5.0  213
5   YCABX    NaN    8.0  213
6     CAC    6.0    6.0  213
7     CAD    2.0    3.0  213
8     CAE    3.0    NaN  213
9    xDAA    NaN    6.0  215
10    EAA    8.0    4.0  222
11    FAA    3.0    NaN  223
```

or this (it doesn't matter if I keep the full name or just the sub_name where the rows match):

```
     name  val_1  val_2    A
0    XAAA    2.0    1.0  208
1   AABYY    4.0    5.0  208
2     AAC    8.0    NaN  208
3    BAAZ    7.0    9.0  210
4    CAAY    4.0    5.0  213
5   YCABX    NaN    8.0  213
6   XXCAC    6.0    6.0  213
7   YCADZ    2.0    3.0  213
8     CAE    3.0    NaN  213
9    XDAA    NaN    6.0  215
10    EAA    8.0    4.0  222
11    FAA    3.0    NaN  223
```

If I needed full match I would use `.merge(df1, df2, how = 'outer')` but since I am working with substrings I don't know how to approach this. Maybe `str.contains()` could be useful?

Note: The sub_name can be made of more than just three letters. This is just an example.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `df2`'s `name` column will not contain `X`, `Y` or `Z`? Then that way, for this specific case, you could do `df2['name'].str.replace(r'[XYZ]', '', regex=True)` and merge based on that.

Comment: Thanks but the letters could be anything (eg name: AABBC match with sub_name: AAB). I just added XYZ for easier understanding.

Comment: Thought so, but I was being hopeful :) This seems pretty trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Create new column, an extraction of df's subname in df2's name

df2['sub_name']=df2['name'].str.findall('|'.join(df1['sub_name'].values.tolist())).str.join(',')

#Do an outer merge

df_new=df2.merge(df1, how='outer', on=['sub_name', 'A'])

#Update the name's columns values and drop the sub_name column created above

df_new=df_new.assign(name=df_new['name'].combine_first(df_new['sub_name'])).drop(columns=['sub_name'])
```

outcome

```
    name  val_2    A  val_1
0    XAAA    1.0  208    2.0
1   AABYY    5.0  208    4.0
2    BAAZ    9.0  210    7.0
3    CAAY    5.0  213    4.0
4   YCABX    8.0  213    NaN
5   XXCAC    6.0  213    6.0
6   YCADZ    3.0  213    2.0
7    XDAA    6.0  215    NaN
8    EAAX    4.0  222    8.0
9     AAC    NaN  208    8.0
10    CAE    NaN  213    3.0
11    FAA    NaN  223    3.0
```

Comment: Thank you, almost what I need. This doen't work for my larger database because I think I would need to first check if the values in column A are the same and then compare like you did. But since I am a newbie I didn't manage to modify your code to work like that. If It would be possible to check columns A first could you edit the code please?

Comment: How do you want to check column A? Describe what you need and will help

Comment: I need to look for the substring only in the rows where the values in column A match. In the database I provided the result would be the same but if in the first column of df1 was for eg. `AA 2 230` (instead of `AAA 2 208`) you would find the `sub_name` AA in many rows of df2. So in `df_new` for eg. in the row AABYY the sub_name found would be AA instead of AAB. But I need there to be AAB since it matches with AABYY in the A column (unlike AA where the A coulumn is 230). It is difficult to describe in the comment but if you modify the first column of `df1` to `AA 2 230` you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [fuzzy match](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz)  with a threshold, then `merge`:

```
from thefuzz import process

def best(x, thresh=80):
    match, score = process.extractOne(x, df2['name'])
    if score>=thresh:
        return match


df1.merge(df2, left_on=['A', df1['sub_name'].apply(best)],
          right_on=['A', 'name'],
          how='outer')
```

Output:

```
   sub_name  val_1    A   name  val_2
0       AAA    2.0  208   XAAA    1.0
1       AAB    4.0  208  AABYY    5.0
2       AAC    8.0  208   None    NaN
3       BAA    7.0  210   BAAZ    9.0
4       CAA    4.0  213   CAAY    5.0
5       CAC    6.0  213  XXCAC    6.0
6       CAD    2.0  213  YCADZ    3.0
7       CAE    3.0  213   None    NaN
8       EAA    8.0  222   EAAX    4.0
9       FAA    3.0  223   None    NaN
10      NaN    NaN  213  YCABX    8.0
11      NaN    NaN  215   XDAA    6.0
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting an Error though 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)'. Do you know what could I be doing wrong?